# How to generate IConfiguration from app.config

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

Is there an easy way to generate `IConfiguration` based on values in `app.config`?

The need is to support a .NET Framework project that depends on a .NET Standard library. I need to pass `IConfiguration` to that .NET Standard library.

I thought about having `appsettings.json` together with `app.config` at the same time, but it would require to overwrite values on runtime because only `app.config` values will be updated based on environment.

Comment: Maybe you could look into creating [your own, custom configuration provider](https://codeburst.io/create-a-custom-configuration-provider-in-asp-net-core-cdd6a32b8ecb) that reads your `app.config` to handle this situation?